# Generate MTM report like it was an Ranorex .rxlog file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, report, microsoft-test-manager, ranorex

On Ranorex I can generate a report (.rxlog) that contains some information about one project of Visual Studio after I run it with a simple cmd command line with the .exe path and arguments. Can I generate a report on Microsoft Test Manager that looks like that same .rxlog file in some way like that?

Comment: It probably helps if you can share what the report looks like...

Comment: Sure @jessehouwing, I need something like this: http://goo.gl/0Buxpz

Comment: I honestly don't know MTM well, but the ranorex report is actually an html document, so if you can generate an html report in MTM then yes you can make a report that looks like an rxlog report